# Using linear regression on (lagged) returns of one stock to predict returns of another

Tags: forecasting, vix, prediction, regression

Suppose I want to build a linear regression to see if returns of one stock can predict returns of another. For example, let's say I want to see if the VIX return on day X is predictive of the S&P return on day (X + 30). How would I go about this?

The naive way would be to form pairs (VIX return on day 1, S&P return on day 31), (VIX return on day 2, S&P return on day 32), ..., (VIX return on day N, S&P return on day N + 30), and then run a standard linear regression. A t-test on the coefficients would then tell if the model has any real predictive power. But this seems wrong to me, since my points are autocorrelated, and I think the p-value from my t-test would underestimate the true p-value. (Though IIRC, the t-test would be *asymptotically* unbiased? Not sure.)

So what should I do? Some random thoughts I have are:

- Take a bunch of bootstrap samples on my pairs of points, and use these to estimate the empirical distribution of my coefficients and p-values. (What kind of bootstrap do I run? And should I be running the bootstrap on the coefficient of the model, or on the p-value?)
- Instead of taking data from consecutive days, only take data from every K days. For example, use (VIX return on day 1, S&P return on day 31), (VIX return on day 11, S&P return on day 41), etc. (It seems like this would make the dataset way too small, though.)

Are any of these thoughts valid? What are other suggestions?

Comment: ARX(1) + GARCH(1,1) ?

Answer (score 11):

A few thoughts.

Yes, your return series are autocorrelated (i.e., stocks don't exactly follow a random walk), so you should use [Newey-West standard errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newey%E2%80%93West_estimator).

If you do this as a univariate regression $$R_{i,t} = \alpha_i + \beta_i R_{j,t-1} + \epsilon_{i,t}$$ then there's almost certainly an omitted variable inside $\epsilon$ that is moving both $R_i$ and $R_j$. So make sure you throw in at least some of the normal "predictors", like market return, default premium, term premium, or the other standard factors ([Fama and French's SMB, HML, and UMD](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html)). In the hedge fund research you also see a [set of seven or so factors](http://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~dah7/HedgeFund/HedgeFund.htm).

Comment: Which of the papers of Hsieh are you referencing exactly?

Comment: @vonjd -- The [11th on list](http://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~dah7/HF-RF.pdf) is the one in which he proposes the seven factors. I haven't read too much of the hedge fund literature, but I have seen more than a few use these factors.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered fitting ARIMA with exogenous regressors model? Linear regression with autocorrelated errors might be appropriate.

R can do this with the arima() function via specifying the xreg argument.

Answer (score 4):

Van Belle describes a basic correction for autocorrelation in a t-test, although it may be hard to wedge it into the regression t-test. For the 1-sample t-test of the mean, the correction is to multiply the t-statistic by $\sqrt{\frac{1 - \rho}{1 + \rho}}$, where $\rho$ is the 1-period autocorrelation (or estimate thereof).

Answer (score 3):

Well vix is a measure of volatitity which would make it an estimate of a second moment for S&P 500 so you might try an arch/garch in the mean type model on S&P.

A good starting place for a project like this is to just do Vector Autoregressions on industry groups that you think might be related and see what comes up.

N+30 is a long way in the future, especially to estimate a return. I would use weekly data and try and estimate a mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is a vector autoregression (VAR) model with restrictions. I would also use a shorter lag and add conventional factors to the VIX return.

Simple bootstrapping destroys the serial correlation in your model, but you might consider block bootstrapping.

I would also try the following test: use a subset to calibrate your model and then perform an out-of-sample step with the next data point of the regressor. Repeat this procedure by shifting the subset by one step (i.e. apply the regression to a rolling time window). This gives you an idea of the stability of the coefficients, and the forecasting ability of the model.